# How to do Metric aggregation inside terms aggregations on nested type

Tags: elasticsearch

I've documents stored in Elastic Search in this way:

**Doc1:**

```
{
  "owner": "owner_1",
  "attributes" : [
    {
      "name": "dump",
      "value": "xyz"
    },
    {
      "name": "weight",
      "value": "150"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Doc2:**

```
{
  "owner": "onwer_2",
  "attributes" : [
    {
      "name": "dump",
      "value": "xyz"
    },
    {
      "name": "weight",
      "value": "600"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Doc3:**

```
{
  "owner": "owner_3",
  "attributes" : [
    {
      "name": "dump",
      "value": "abc"
    },
    {
      "name": "weight",
      "value": "40"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Note:** *`attributes` is a nested type field.*

---

**Problem statement:**

1. Retrieve documents that have the `name` *dump* in their `attributes` field.
2. Perform an aggregation based on the `value` of *dump* **(abc, xyz)**.
3. Calculate the total *weight* for all documents that have the same *dump* value obtained from the previous step.

The result for the documents mentioned above resembles the following:

```
{
  ...
  "aggregations": {
    ...
    "buckets": [
      {
        "key": "xyz",
        "doc_count": 2,
        "weight": {
          "value": 800
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "abc",
        "doc_count": 1,
        "weight": {
          "value": 40
        }
      }
    ]    
  }
}
```

---

**What steps I've taken so far?**

I've prepared the following query.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "doc.attributes",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "doc.attributes.name.keyword": "dump"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "attributes": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "doc.attributes"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "NAME_BUCKET": {
          "filter": {
            "terms": {
              "doc.attributes.name.keyword": [
                "dump",
                "weight"
              ]
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "VALUE_BUCKET": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "doc.attributes.value.keyword",
                "size": 100
              },
              "aggs": {
                "weight": {
                  "sum": {
                    "script": {
                      "lang": "painless",
                      "source": """
                      if(doc['doc.attributes.name.keyword'].value == "weight") {
                        return Double.parseDouble(doc['doc.attributes.value.keyword'].value);
                      }
                      return 0;
                      """
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above query produces output similar to this:

```
{
  ...,
  ...,
  "buckets": [
    {
      "key": "abc",
      "doc_count": 1,
      "Payment": {
        "value": 0.0
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "xyz",
      "doc_count": 2,
      "Payment": {
        "value": 0.0
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "150",
      "doc_count": 1,
      "Payment": {
        "value": 150.0
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "40",
      "doc_count": 1,
      "Payment": {
        "value": 40.0
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "650",
      "doc_count": 1,
      "Payment": {
        "value": 650.0
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Of course, the above query doesn't yield the expected output. The *NAME_BUCKET* aggregation aggregates records based on the *dump* and *weight* fields so that they can be used later in the Painless script. However, I am currently unable to determine how to aggregate *weight* based on the value of *dump*."

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It's not possible to do it the way you've set up your mapping. `dump` and `weight` need to be in the **same** nested document if you want to correlate them, otherwise they are considered as different documents and there's no way to "glue" them together anymore, even in a scripted aggregation. If your nested documents looked like `{"dump": "xyz", "weight": 150}` it would be possible to achieve what you want.